# Android Size Analyzer Plugin - WebP Conversion Settings

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, android-gradle-plugin, webp

I installed the [ASA plugin](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size#size-analyzer) in Android Studio today, and ran the "Analyze App Size" job.
I accepted the conversion to convert PNGs to WEBPs, which works great.

However, going forward as I add assets to my project, I want to make sure that I am converting new PNGs to WEBP *with the same settings...*

I have searched the [source code of the plugin](https://github.com/android/size-analyzer/blob/e236f2ae4a73f38c8375e726693a1193696fb1e2/analyzer/src/main/java/com/android/tools/sizereduction/analyzer/suggesters/Suggestion.java), but it seems to just defer the suggestion to the internal AS conversion code with some hidden parameter...

Does anyone know what the conversion parameters are or how I can find them?